# Set transparency of a DIV and its contents using jQuery

Tags: jquery, transparency, effects

What is the best way to set the transparency of a HTML DIV element and its contents using jQuery?

Comment: Transparency is the same as opacity.  Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19602620/445131

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`$('#my_element').css({ 'opacity' : 0.7 });`

Do you want to actually set the opacity to each of the contained elements as well, or you just  want it to 'appear' as if the child elements have the same opacity?

As an example to my question, if you wanted something that sets an element, and each of the children elements, you could do something like this

**html**

```
<div id="my_element">
  <div>
    lorem
  </div>
  <div>
    ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#my_element').children().
                 css({ 'opacity' : 0.25 }).
                 end().
                 css({ 'opacity' : 0.25 });
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 10):

Another option - Save your keyboard and use [fadeTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeTo):

```
$('#someDiv').fadeTo("slow",0.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

As theIV said you can use the css method, but as an alternative you can use animate:

```
$('#my_element').animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 100);
```

this will animate the opacity of you div (and its contents) to 0.5 (from whatever it was to begin with) in 100 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try this properties

`$('#my_div').css("opacity", "0.5");` //Immediately sets opacity
`$('#my_div').fadeTo(0, 0.5);`        //Animates the opacity to 50% over the course of 0 milliseconds.  Increase the 0 if you want to animate it.
`$('#my_div').fadeIn();`              //Animates the opacity from 0 to 100%